# Combine multiple rows per ID into one row per ID R

Tags: r, dplyr, rows, na

Given the dataframe `df1` below, I would like to convert this into the dataframe `df2`. Ideally the goal is to Combine multiple rows per ID into one row per ID. If the solution can be implemented in dplyr, tidyverse, etc., that would be great!!

```
df1 <- data.frame (ID  = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2",
                           "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3",
                           "4", "4"),
                   fruit_name = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                                  "Orange", "Blueberry", "Peach",
                                  "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                                  "Orange", "Blueberry", "Peach",
                                  "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                                  "Orange", "Blueberry",
                                  "Apple", "Cherry"),
                   count_one = c("2", "2", "2",
                                  "2", "2", "2",
                                  "4", "4", "4",
                                  "4", "4", "4",
                                  "3", "3", "3",
                                  "3", "3",
                                  "5", "5"),
                   count_two = c("1", "NA", "NA",
                                 "NA", "NA", "NA",
                                 "NA", "NA", "4",
                                 "NA", "NA", "NA",
                                 "NA", "NA", "NA",
                                 "NA", "3",
                                 "5", "NA"))
```

INTO...

```
df2 <- data.frame (ID  = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                   count_one = c("2", "4", "3", "5"),
                   count_two = c("1", "4", "3", "5"))
```

Thank you and much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to aggregate on ID and return the maximum count_one, maximum count_two?  fruit_name has no impact for the question?

Comment: What's the logic by the way? First value/last value??

Comment: So for `count_one`, just the unique number by `ID` and for `count_two`, just the non-null value by `ID`

Comment: Yes correct, `fruit_name` has no impact on the question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% distinct(ID,count_one,count_two) %>% filter(count_two != "NA")
```

However, you should consider your counts must be `numeric` class. You can transform them like this:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(count_one = as.numeric(count_one),
               count_two = as.numeric(recode(count_two,"NA"=NA_character_)))
```

Now you can apply different strategies:

With `R base`:

```
df2 <- na.omit(df1)
df2$fruit_name <- NULL
```

With `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% select(-fruit_name) %>% drop_na()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the pivot_wider function. I know it isn't really necessary here but it gets the job done.

```
df2 <- df1[,-2] %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, count_one, count_two)) %>%
  na.rm()
```

I did recode the NA values to not be characters first in order to get the na.rm to function